# Comparing a name in a Column and alarming through a modal if there is a duplicate found. Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

The code given is an example of what I would like to happen but I don't know how to apply it in a way that it would run smoothly or if it is possible at all. I just want to know how to do it and what other ways I can do it for educational purposes and for future coding projects.

```
function DuplicatePatient(triggerPatient) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B:B").getValues();
  var columnB = ["B"]
  var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var patient = ss.getRange(columnB + lastrow);
  var triggerPatient = patient.getValue();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi
  var row = [rownumber]

  if (triggerPatient == values){
    return ui.alert("Duplicate Found on row" + row)
  }
}
```

I would totally appreciate it if you guys would enlighten me with the subject at hand and I hope it can help other people as reference. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A few corrections

You can achieve the desired functionality based on your code snippet when implementing the following modifications:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2-D array. To know if a value is already contained in `values`, you need to convert this 2-D array into a 1-D one (for example with [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)).
- The next step would be to either [loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) through each single value and look for correspondance with `triggerPatient` via the `==` operator or - more elegant to use a method that tells you directly either `triggerPatient` is contained in the `values` array.
- For the latter you can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which not only tells you if the duplicate is found, but also at which index (position) of the array. This allows you to calculate the corresponding row.
- Keep in mind that `"B:B"` contains all values of column B - inlcluding `triggerPatient` in the last row. To look for duplicates you want to excluded this last row from the comparison. You can do so for example by removing the last value from the `values` array with [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
- Note that `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` is a method and thus needs to be called with `()` at the end.

A sample what a working code could look like:

```js
function DuplicatePatient() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B:B").getValues();
  values = values.flat();
  values.pop();
  // just to visualize the results:
  console.log(values);
  var columnB = ["B"];
  var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var patient = ss.getRange(columnB + lastrow);
  var triggerPatient = patient.getValue();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var duplicateRow = 1 + values.indexOf(triggerPatient);
  if (duplicateRow > 0){
    return ui.alert("Duplicate Found on row " + duplicateRow)
  }
}
```

If you have any further doubts about the methods used, I invite you to have a closer look at the respective documentation.

Comment: Thank you for educating me which was the purpose of this query. I absolutely got what you mean and I have learned more than what ive asked for. Thank you for this again!

Comment: Apparently the Modal doesn't work on Trigger and returns an Exception. Any way around this?

Comment: And also to add, The pop method didnt work for it and it still indicates the currently added value as a duplicate.

Comment: It's true, you cannot use a modal dialog on trigger (because the trigger will fire even if the spreadsheet is not being opened). You would need another solution like e.g. emailing the user / the admin about the duplicate or simply omit the alert and ony skip adding the duplicate.

Comment: As for the pop method: What is the output of `console.log(values)`? You might want to try `  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B:B"+ ss.getLastRow()).getValues();` to make sure that only the non-empty contents containing range is retrieved. If you have empty trailing values at the end of the `values` array - possibly you have more data containing rows on other columns than B. Hard to say without knowing the structure of your spreadsheet.